# Tkinter - How to move image from canvas in slow motion

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

guys. I am trying to create my own version of a card game. I got the following problem trying to move my cards to the center of the canvas on click event. Here is an example of my code

```
import tkinter as tk

class gui(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
    self.canvas =  tk.Canvas(parent, bg="blue", highlightthickness=0)
    self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    self.img = PhotoImage(file="card.gif")
    self.card = self.canvas.create_image(10, 10, image=self.img)
    self.canvas.tag_bind(self.card, '<Button-1>', self.onObjectClick1)

def onObjectClick1(self, event):
    if self.canvas.find_withtag("current"):
        x = 400
        y = 400
        self.canvas.coords("current", x, y)
        self.canvas.tag_raise("current")

if __name__ == "__main__":
root = tk.Tk()
w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
gui(root)
root.mainloop()
```

What I want is to move my card but not just move from one coordinate to another but giving it in slow motion effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is to write a function that moves an object a small amount, and then schedules itself to be called again after a short delay. It does this until it reaches its destination.

Here is a very simple example that moves a couple items independently. You can adjust the speed by changing the `speed` parameter, or by changing the values of `delta_x` and `delta_y`.

This is a very simplistic algorithm that just increases the x and y coordinates by a fixed amount. You could instead calculate equally spaced points along a curve or straight line. Regardless, the animation technique remains the same.

```
import Tkinter as tk

def move_object(canvas, object_id, destination, speed=50):
    dest_x, dest_y = destination
    coords = canvas.coords(object_id)
    current_x = coords[0]
    current_y = coords[1]

    new_x, new_y = current_x, current_y
    delta_x = delta_y = 0
    if current_x < dest_x:
        delta_x = 1
    elif current_x > dest_x:
        delta_x = -1

    if current_y < dest_y:
        delta_y = 1
    elif current_y > dest_y:
        delta_y = -1

    if (delta_x, delta_y) != (0, 0):
        canvas.move(object_id, delta_x, delta_y)

    if (new_x, new_y) != (dest_x, dest_y):
        canvas.after(speed, move_object, canvas, object_id, destination, speed)

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()

item1 = canvas.create_rectangle(10, 10, 30, 30, fill="red")
item2 = canvas.create_rectangle(360, 10, 380, 30, fill="green")

move_object(canvas, item1, (200, 180), 25)
move_object(canvas, item2, (200, 220), 50)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi, can you please tell how to speed up this a little by changing the values of `delta_x` and `delta_y`?

Comment: @sodmzs: you mean, something like `delta_x = .5` or `delta_x = 1.2`?

Comment: No. Actually I want the speed to be little more fast, so I changed the value of speed to `speed=1` but still it's little slower than the desired output. So what should I do ?

Comment: have you tried changing `speed` to some other value? It's just basic math. Either move the object a greater distance in each time period, or move it the same distance but more times per second.

Answer (score 1):

In order to 'animate' your cards moving, a system of breaking down the total distance to be moved, and then moving/updating by smaller distances over a time-period would work.

For example, if you wish to move a card 400 units in x & y, something like this could work:

```
total_time = 500 #Time in milliseconds
period = 8
dx = 400/period
dy = 400/period

for i in range(period):
    self.canvas.move(chosen_card, dx, dy)
    root.after(total_time/period) #Pause for time, creating animation effect
    root.update() #Update position of card on canvas
```

This could be a basic premise for an animation. Of course you would need to edit the `total_time` and `period` variables in my example to create what you feel is right.

Comment: `root.after(total_time/period)` is effectively putting the app to sleep. That's not going to result in a good user experience.

Answer (score 0):

This code below (ready for copy/paste and run as it is) gives a nice smooth motion on my box:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

class gui(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.canvas =  tk.Canvas(parent, bg="blue", highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        self.img = tk.PhotoImage(file="card.gif")
        self.card = self.canvas.create_image(10, 10, image=self.img)
        self.canvas.tag_bind(self.card, '<Button-1>', self.onObjectClick1)

    def onObjectClick1(self, event):
        if self.canvas.find_withtag("current"):
            x = 400
            y = 400
            self.canvas.coords("current", x, y)
            self.canvas.tag_raise("current")
            total_time = 500 #Time in milliseconds
        period = 400
        dx = 400/period
        dy = 400/period
        for i in range(period):
            self.canvas.move(self.card, dx, dy) # chosen_card
            time.sleep(0.01)
            # root.after(total_time/period) #Pause for time, creating animation effect
            root.update() #Update position of card on canvas

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
    root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
    gui(root)
    root.mainloop()
```